# C++ gtkmm 3 HeaderBar and Notebook with autohide animation

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

How can I:
1) properly set Gtk::Notebook in Gtk::HeaderBar like:

```
window.add(box);
```

2) implement autohide tabs ( animated like css transitions with scale(0) and scale(1) ) ?

My code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Gtk::Main app(argc, argv);
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(200, 200);
    Gtk::HBox box;
    Gtk::HeaderBar titlebar;
    Gtk::Notebook notebook;
    Gtk::TextView text;
    notebook.append_page(text, "First");
    box.pack_start(notebook);
    titlebar.set_custom_title(box);
    window.set_titlebar(titlebar);
    window.show_all_children();
    return app.run(window);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement the tabbed window titlebars thing, [like this one here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/aboutdialog.png)? If so, you want GtkStackSwitcher, not GtkNotebook. To make the GtkStackSwitcher centered, use `GtkHeaderBar::set_custom_title()`. I'm not sure what you mean with the animations, but if you want the tab transitions to be animated, use a GtkStack for your window content area instead of a GtkNotebook. GtkStack should have some transition animations available to choose from (this may depend on your version of GTK+).

Comment: @andlabs: Yes, but something like: GtkStackSwitcher + GtkNoteBook ( reorderable like firefox and chrome tabs ). Animations - tabbar autohide like: http://jsfiddle.net/91z6mzbp/